# Universal solution for changing structures using reflection

Tags: go, reflection

Suppose I have a structure with several nested structures:

```golang
type SomeInt int
type AnotherConfig struct {
    Value1 string
    Value2 int
    Value3 SomeInt
}
type SubConf struct {
    Value1 string
    Value2 int
    Conf   AnotherConfig
}
type Config struct {
    Value1 string
    Value2 int
    Conf   SubConf
}
```

I need an implementation of a function that will take as input a **path** from some **final scalar field**, and set there a value that will automatically be converted to the appropriate type:

```golang
func (conf *Config) ChangeValue(path string, value string) {
    //Need implementation
}

func main() {
    conf := Config{}
    // Usage example:
    conf.ChangeValue("Conf.Conf.Value3", "123")
}
```

Nested structures can constantly change during development, so a more or less universal solution is needed. Perhaps with support for a limited set of type conversions, such as support for only **strings** and **ints**, but they can be typed (as in the example).

Comment: If you're asking for a library, that's off-topic. If you're asking if this is possible, yes. What have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you encounter?

Comment: I need at least some example of how to work with the reflection of nested fields. How to access final field. Suppose I decompose the path into a slice by point. What to do next?

Comment: There are many examples of this in the standard library. Perhaps look at the `encoding/json` package.